# Eclipse won't run my java programs and gives me this useless error

Tags: java, eclipse

I recently can't run any of my java programs an JUnit test anymore. Eclipse gives me this vague error code and I can't seem to find the solution

[image: the error code eclipse gives me]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Also include details like which version of Eclipse this is, and how it was downloaded and installed.

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message. [Edit] your question to show us the extra detail.